# Time zone added to hour after using nsdateformatter

Tags: iphone, timezone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to convert a string date (2011-06-08T08:05:00.000-08:00) into a NSDate using the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
//Translate 2011-06-08T08:05:00.000-08:00 into 2011-06-08T08:05:00.000-0800
stringDate = [stringDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange([aDate length] - 5, 5)];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.SSSZZZ"];  
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];
```

At this point, dateFromString is 2011-06-08 16:05:00 +0000. What I actually wanted was for dateFromString to be 2011-06-08 08:05:00 -0800. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, you probably need to set the time zone for the output to -0800 GMT.

Comment: The link does not help unfortunately. Regarding the time zone, I already tried using [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:time_zone]]; with time_zone being UTC, or GMT, but nothing changed.

Comment: GMT is +0000, correct? So it worked.

Comment: Well, I need the time zone to match the one from the stringDate, and I don;t know that time zone in advance.

Comment: You can read a timeZone as easily as you can set one.

Comment: How can I read a time zone from a string date?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSTimeZone

Comment: I tried using [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:(-8 * 3600)]] but it did not make any difference. If you know exactly what to do, please let me know. I've been working on this for some time now but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

So this will not have a direct answer and will assume that your string format will be the same. What we are going to extract the timezone part (last 5 characters) and then calculate how many seconds we are off from GMT. `NSTimeZone` has a convenience method `timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:` that will help us get what we need. This is what you need to add to the code in the question.

```
NSString * zoneString = [stringDate substringFromIndex:([stringDate length] - 5)];
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [[zoneString substringToIndex:3] intValue] * 3600;
timeInterval += [[zoneString substringFromIndex:3] intValue] * 60;

NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:timeInterval]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss ZZZ"];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:dateFromString]);
```

Hopefully this helps you. If you've found a better answer already, let us know.

**Original Answer**
One thing about the `NSDate` is that the time returned is always in GMT. You can't change that. You will have to use an `NSDateFormatter` to print it right. Something like this,

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"PST"]];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

So setting the timezone for the formatter that does `dateForString:` won't help. You will need to create a new one when you want them with a different timezone.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is with the assumption that the time zone is PST. There is no way to know that before hand. I tried using strptime_l as mentioned in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1, but the format that I supply just doesn't work.

Comment: according to the question, shouldn't this extract the last 6 characters, and then ignore the colon? how does it handle with the signing of the timezone? (specifically subtraction)